# using sharepoint client object model need to update item from one list to another in batch

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I am making windows tool using sharepoint client object model. I have two custom lists one as source list and another as destination list hosted in sharepoint. In both the lists there is column Application ID which will act like unique key.

I have a button update list which will update the destination list item in batch if Application  ID of source list is equal to Application ID of destination List.

Please guide me how to prcodeed .

Thanks
Rakesh

Answer (score 2):

Following is an example of batch updating list items:

```
function updateListItems() {

    var itemArray = [];
    var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('TestList');


    for(var i = 1; i<= 5; i++){

        var oListItem = oList.getItemById(i);  
        oListItem.set_item('Title', 'My Updated Item!' + i);  
        oListItem.update();
        itemArray[i] = oListItem;
        clientContext.load(itemArray[i]);
    }

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySucceeded, onQueryFailed);
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {

    alert('Items Updated');
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
updateListItems();
```

Notice that query is executed at the end after loading all items in the `for` loop.

Source: http://www.vrdmn.com/2013/07/batch-operations-using-javascript.html

Comment: If he is making a windows application, perhaps using C# and _Microsoft.SharePoint.Client_ is more appropriate? Although the code would be very similar. And do you really need the `.load`?

Comment: You are right Managed client object model will make more sense than Javascript client object model. However, .Load will still be needed and executeQueryAsync will change to ExecuteQuery()

Comment: `.load` is for loading data, not updating, I would just call `update`. This code should work perfectly: `c=SP.ClientContext.get_current(),i=c.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Test').addItem();i.set_item('Title','test');i.update();c.executeQueryAsync()`, and it can be looped (batched) just as well as far as I know

Comment: Hi eirikb,
You are correct I am using C#. But I need to compare two columns i.e. application IDs from both the lists and than update item if both items have same value of application. For that I used CAML query but no success. Please help..

Comment: @rakeshpandey You should share the CAML query and the code you have written so far.

Comment: Nadeem and Eirikb Thanks for your support. Finally able to resolve the issue. Actually I created a Public void updatelist(string colID) under which i compared the two caml queries and after that on button click event call the above method. helpful link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798388.aspx

Guys once again thanks for your support.

Comment: @rakeshpandey can you post your solution here and accept it? This way others can benefit from it.